# find files with basename matching pattern while returning full path

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression

I need to match results of `find` with regexp. The files are as:

```
/path/1/file1.001.txt
/path/1/file2.001.txt
/path/1/file1.001
/path/2/file3.002.txt
/path/2/pure_file3.002.txt
```

etc.

I need to match all files from all directories ending in `xxx.txt` where `xxx` are 3 digits and only those filenames that are not preceded by word `pure_`. Further, I need to return the full path.

I have all working except excluding the files preceded by `pure_`:

```
find /path/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type f | grep -P '.*\.[0-9]{3}.txt'
```

I tried:

```
find /path/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type f | grep -P '.+(?!pure).*\.[0-9]{3}.txt'
```

but if I do in say `/path/1/`:

```
ls -1 | grep -P '^(?!pure).*\.[0-9]{3}.txt'
```

that correctly excludes those files, on the other hand:

```
ls -1 | grep -P '(?!pure).*\.[0-9]{3}.txt'
```

does not.

So it probably boils down to, how to match within a full path a basename that does not start with `pure_`. My understanding of regular expressions is insufficient for that, it may have something to do with the atomicity of look arounds which i never understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just tell `find` to exclude files that begin with `pure_`, and also do the `grep` with the `-regex` expression:

```
find ./path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type f ! -name 'pure_*' -regex '.*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt$'
```

With copies in a simulated directory from your example, I get:

```
./path/1/file1.001.txt
./path/1/file2.001.txt
./path/2/file3.002.txt
```

Comment: Depending on your `find` implementation, you can use `[0-9]{3}` with either `-regextype posix-extended` or `regextype Extended`

Answer (score 3):

`find` without regular expression matching:

```
find /path -type f ! -name 'pure_*' -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt'
```

This will find any regular file in or under the `/path` directory whose name does not start with `pure_` but ends in three digits and `.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type f | egrep "[0-9]{3}\.txt$" | grep -v pure_
```

The `find` looks for files starting in your current directory.

The `egrep` applies extended regexps, filtering for three digits appended by ".txt" (the dots needs to be escaped as otherwise "Atxt" would match, too), at the end of a line.

The `grep` filters away (`-v`) lines with the string "pure_" (I am not sure if the place of the "pure_" is important).

Comment: This would not report files in a directory called `pure_files` (for example).